# Is it possible to calculate each all the numbers received on each day of the week from this list in Python? I don't understand splitting

Tags: python

```
import os
myFilePath = os.getcwd()
print(myFilePath)
calls = open('/Users/fake/Desktop/fakefolder/calls.txt')
mondayCalls = []
for adding in calls.readlines():
    mondayCalls.append(adding.strip())
calls.close()
print(mondayCalls)
```

Here is the list that I generated from a txt file, I just want to add the total for all mondays, tuesdays etc. I would want to print

```
Monday = 29
Tuesday = 16 etc
```

The list is longer but here is an example of the list that I have.

```
['Monday:21', 'Tuesday:6', 'Wednesday:8', 'Thursday:18', 'Friday:16', 'Saturday:4', 'Sunday:10', 'Monday:8']
```

Comment: Alright, so what's the problem? You wrote _I don't understand splitting_, can you be more specific?

Comment: I was told splitting is the best way bit I recently started reading up on it so I don't understand it as yet. I want to just pull from the list and calculate the number associated with each day.

Comment: Which part of splitting don’t you understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (explanation in code comments):

```
list = ['Monday:21', 'Tuesday:6', 'Wednesday:8', 'Thursday:18', 'Friday:16', 'Saturday:4', 'Sunday:10', 'Monday:8']
# create a dictionary variable
days_dict = {}
# for every entry in the list
for entry in list:
    # split entry by ":" and take the first part of the entry
    day = entry.split(":")[0]
    # split entry by ":" and take the second part of the entry and convert it to an integer
    count = int(entry.split(":")[1])
    print (day)
    print (count)
    # if the day key is in the dictionary add to its count else create the key
    if day in days_dict:
        days_dict[day] += count
    else:
        days_dict[day] = count

print (days_dict)
# print Monday's count
print ('Monday Count = ' + str(days_dict['Monday']))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with splitting and then recording values in a dictionary. You can iterate through the list and store the values in a dictionary where the key of the dictionary is the day. Pseudo code below:

```
record = {}    
for entry in list:
    day = get_day(entry)
    val = get_val(entry)
    if day in record:
        record[day] += val
    else:
        record[day] = val
```

Then your final `record_dict` will contain the values you want for each day.